# Hopf algebra: Why is the final target $A$ rather than $A\otimes A$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras

Let $A$ be a hopf algebra associated to some linear algebraic group.

I read that:
\begin{array}{ccc}A&\overset{id\otimes\iota}\longleftarrow&A\otimes A\\\iota\otimes id\uparrow&&\uparrow \Delta\\A\otimes A&\overset{\Delta}{\longleftarrow}&A\end{array}

must be satisfied, where $\iota$ is the coinverse. I am unsure why these live in the places that they do. Shouldn't $\iota:A\to A$ and $id:A\to A$ mean that $\iota\otimes id:A\otimes A \to A\otimes A$, why is the last square just $A$?

Comment: The tensor in the mappings here should be read as a multiplication. So, $a \otimes b$ is sent by $\iota \otimes \mathrm{id}$ to $\iota(a)b$.

Comment: @MeesdeVries That would fix my concern. How do I distinguish when that is the case? I.e. $\Delta \otimes id$ should definitely map $A\otimes A\to A\otimes A\otimes A$ right?

Comment: I can see why $\epsilon \otimes id$ would map $A\otimes A\to A$, since it'll take the left term into the field, but in this case I just don't see it.

Comment: I think the notation in the diagram is just bad. It should explicitly mention a multiplication mapping somewhere. But in this case you can tell what they mean by looking at the domain/codomain.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Is this coinverse actually the antipode? I am trying to compare to other notes, and it seems like it might be

Comment: Yes, those are synonyms. (At least as far as I know.)

Comment: @MeesdeVries Thanks very much!